# Migration from Swift 2.3 to 3.0 Invalid type in JSON write

Tags: json, swift3, migration

I Have the following

```
class :class JsonDomain : EVObject {
    func jsonValue() -> NSDictionary {
        return self.toDictionary()
    }
}
```

and

```
class TokenValor :JsonDomain {
    var to : Token!
    var valor : NSDecimalNumber = 0

    convenience init(to : Token?, valor : NSDecimalNumber?) {
        self.init()
        self.to =  to!
        self.valor = getOptionalDecimalValue(valor)
    }

    override func jsonValue() -> NSDictionary {
        let cifrado = Token()
        cifrado.chave = CryptService.cifrar(to.chave)
        let tokenValor = TokenValor(to: cifrado, valor: self.valor)
        return tokenValor.toDictionary()
    }


    override func getValidationsArray() ->  JsonTypeValidation {
        return [("to","Token"),("valor", "Valor")]
    }
}
```

And the method jsonValue() is returning me :

**{

            to = "Token = {\n "chave" : "-100;76;-79;81;81;-18;76;23;"\n}";

               valor = 50;

       }**

This is giving me the following error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (MyApp.Token)'"

I am currently using Swift 3, EvReflection with branch "Swift3" and SwiftyJSON 3.1.4.
When using Swift 2.3 with version EvReflection 2.6 did not give this error

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just update the EVReflection to the master branch. And I changed my code to:

```
class TokenValor : JsonDomain
{
    var to : Token?
    var valor : NSDecimalNumber = 0

    convenience init(to : Token, valor : NSDecimalNumber?) {
        self.init()
        self.to =  to
        self.valor = getOptionalDecimalValue(valor)
    }

    override func jsonValue() -> NSDictionary {
        let cifrado = Token()
        cifrado.chave = CryptService.cifrar((to?.chave)!)
        let tokenValor = TokenValor(to: cifrado, valor: self.valor)
        return tokenValor.toDictionary()
    }


    override func getValidationsArray() ->  JsonTypeValidation {
        return [("to","Token"),("valor", "Valor")]
    }
}
```